# VPN Connection don't have access to remote access to VM's

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

my problem is: Within the LAN have remote access virtual machines, including the VM's (xx1.11 and xx1.26).

Working through vpn in remote location, have access to the entire LAN, have remote access to all machines in the domain, not only have access to the virtual machine (xx1.11 and xx1.26).

You can see the network scheme on below
[image]

bests

Comment: You will need to modify the network configuration so that the remote VMs are visible to the VPN Tunnel also.  If you don't have the that ability, you can't solve this yourself, my guess there is a specific reason this wasn't done already.

Comment: Ok @Ramhound setting's that have to modify?

Comment: I know nothing about your network.